# Body background-color strange behavior

Tags: html, css, background

Suppose we have a simple HTML page:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
</body>
</html>
```

Browsers (except for IE) would render it like this:

[image]

The question is why does the area outside the body element (which itself is 100px wide and 100px high) have a red background?

Comment: see: http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres

Answer (score 3):

'cause body is your entire document.
you can't limit it to 100x100px.

you may use a div to create your box :

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Porret: Please change that inline CSS stuff to something with the CSS in the <head> or so.

Comment: yeap, you're right, but that was only for the code example ;)

Comment: "'cause body is your entire document" -- why then border is drawn not around the entire document?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume because you havent specified a background color for your 100x100px square? (only a guess without seeing more of your CSS code)

Answer (score 0):

Because the bodys background is the one that the whole page gets assigned, too. What would you expect? A white background that you can't get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

This example can be made to work, but you will need to apply styles to both the HTML tag and the BODY tag, like so:

```
<html style="background-color:white;">
<head></head>
<body style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is essentially correct. As far as I can tell, the viewport adopts the background colour of the html element if it is defined, otherwise the background colour of the body element if that is defined, otherwise it is white.